# Stored procedure changes the datetime format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that receives some parameters and then returns results. The stored procedure receives a `DateTime` parameter with the following format `'2012.01.06'`. Then I simply want to return this `DateTime` parameter. It works fine, but the returned `DateTime` has this format `Jan  6 2012 12:00AM`. I want to change it so that it looks the same as the way as the passed parameter on first place.

Here is a part of my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myTestProcedure]
 @myTestDate dateTime
 AS
 BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @TempTestData TABLE
 (
  Name$ VARCHAR(50),
  Value$ VARCHAR (50)
 )

 INSERT INTO @TempTestData SELECT  'Date1', @fromDate 
 SELECT * from @TempTestData

 END
 GO
```

Comment: question makes no sense. DateTime has no format. You appear to be confusing representation with presentation.

Comment: Date is date how it looks it only matters to the view(application) that displays the value?

Comment: @ Dalorzo: that's what I already said! :)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat okay, i'm confused, what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: The point is, I'm not sure what you are trying to do!

Comment: @Dalorzo, exactly, it is important for my c# application, but i thought that I can get it the way i want from the stored procedure. looks like i have to convert it to this format in c#, am I mistaking?

Comment: @Ivo make sure you return a date type from the store proc and let c# handle the formatting of it

Comment: okay, thanks, i'll do the conversion in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your code, you're receiving a datetime parameter,and storing it in a varchar column. You're passing a string to your procedure, that is parsed as a datetime, and then formatetd to be stored in your table. And then you returned the date with the new format.

If you change the type of your parameter to varchar, there will be no parsing neither formatting, thus you'll store and recover the original value.

If you really want to treat is as date use [Cast and convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) explcitly. Use an strign parameter, and parse an format it manually, deciding which format you accept and wchich format you return.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, since it answers the question, but I've decided to do the conversion in c# and am not using the above suggested method.